# get records & column names from dataframe where atleast one column value of a record is True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a dataframe as follows:

```
flight_id | from_location  | to_location |  schedule |  
1         |   Vancouver    |   Toronto   |   3-Jan   |  
2         |   Amsterdam    |   Tokyo     |   15-Feb  |  
4         |   None         |   Glasgow   |   12-Jan  |  
9         |   Halmstad     |   Athens    |   21-Jan  |  
3         |   Brisbane     |   None      |   4-Feb   |  
4         |   Johannesburg |   Venice    |   12-Jan  |
9         |   None         |  None       |   3-Mar   |
```

I want to get only those record index values where atleast one of the columns `from_location` ,`to_location` is `None`. Also the record index should be tupled with column name that qualified it for selection(i.e the column name whose value is `None` in that record.

Output for above example should be like:
`[(2,from_location),(4,to_location),(6,from_location),(6,to_location)]`

1st element in tuple: record index
2nd element in tuple: column_name in that record index whose value is `None`

I did this:- `df[df[['flight_id','to_location']].isnull().any(axis=1)].index.values.tolist()`
But, that gives me only the record index values `[2,4,6]`. I also want corresponding column names as described above

Any ideas folks?

Comment: Should your example output have index `6` for the last two elements?

Comment: Yes, I edited it now. sample output should be as it is shown now. Earlier I typed it wrong

Answer (score 1):

I think your sample output is wrong base on your description

```
s=df.set_index('flight_id').stack(dropna=False)    
s[s=='None'].index.tolist()#s[s.isnull()]
Out[625]: 
[(4, 'from_location'),
 (3, 'to_location'),
 (9, 'from_location'),
 (9, 'to_location')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `np.where`:

```
x,y = np.where(df == 'None') 
# if those 'None' are np.nan
# use x,y = np.where(df.isnull()) 
list(tuple(zip(df.index[x],df.columns[y])))
```

Output (if flight_id is in the index):

```
[(4, 'from_location'),
 (3, 'to_location'),
 (9, 'from_location'),
 (9, 'to_location')]
```

Else if flight_id is not in the index:

```
[(2, 'from_location'),
 (4, 'to_location'),
 (6, 'from_location'),
 (6, 'to_location')]
```